# Unexpected results with fgets

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(31);
    FILE *fp = fopen("td.txt", "r");
    char* temps[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        fgets(buf, 3, fp);
        temps[i] = buf;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I tried to read from a text like:

```
a
b
c
d
```

So I think the result of temps should be:

```
temp[0] = 'a\n'
...
temp[3] = 'd\n'
```

But the actual result is:

```
temp[0] = 'd\n'
...
temp[3] = 'd\n'
```

After debugging I find every time after `fgets` run suddenly temps change for no reason.
How did this happen? How should I correct my code?

Comment: What language are you really using, `C` or `C++`?  Please choose one.  Once you do that, this does not do what you think it does: `temps[i] = buf;`.  It doesn't create copies of strings -- that's why we need to know what language you're using.

Comment: Well, you make every `temps[i]` point to the same buffer, so they can't contain different strings.

Comment: One way around it is to use `temp[i] = strdup(buf);` — remembering to free the strings when you're done.  Another way is to gradually work through `buf`, using a different section of the 31-byte array for each value: `char *buffer = buf; size_t buflen = 31; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { if (fgets(buffer, buflen, stdin) == 0) break; temp[i] = buffer; size_t length = strlen(buffer) + 1; buffer += length; buflen -= buflen; }` or thereabouts (untested code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buf` points to an allocation whose data contents changes with each `fgets()`.

`temps[i] = buf;` assigns the pointer `buf` to `temps[i]`.  After 4 iterations, `temps[0]`, `temps[1]`, `temps[2]`, `temps[3]` all have the same pointer value.  They all point to same place as `buf`.

---

> How should I correct my code?

To save unique copies of user input, use a large buffer to read user input.  Then allocate right-size buffers for a copy of input.

```
#define N 4
#define BUF_SZ 100

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp = fopen("td.txt", "r");
  if (fp) {
    char buf[BUF_SZ];
    char* temps[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) {
        temps[i] = strdup(buf);
      } else {
        temps[i] = NULL;   
      }
    }

    // Use temps[] somehow

    // cleanup
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      free(temps[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
```

Comment: My goal is to make temps[1] = 'a' ... temps[3] = 'd', I know the mistakes now and I have corrected my code. Thank you for your help with my first question.